# Create a shortcut/widget to an Accessibility feature

Tags: ios, accessibility, widgets, shortcuts-app

I would like to build a shortcut to General -> Accessibility -> MFI Hearing Devices -> Adam Hearing Devices -> Stream to left hearing device, and toggle that off/on. I've been searching the [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios) documentation but can't find a way to do this. Is it possible, maybe with another app?

Answer (score -1):

If you go into General -> Accessibility -> Accessibility Shortcut, is there an option to add 'Stream to left hearing device'?

If so, you can then triple click on the home button and that should (providing you haven't enabled any other accessibility features) toggle the stream.

Unfortunately I do not have a MFI device to test this with, however I do use the accessibility shortcuts frequently.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: That's a shame.